# passing return value from jsonp to php

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp

How can I return the value **yes** or **no** to php function .If not can i do the same jsonp functionality with curl ?

```
$.ajax({
        url:    'www.example.com/trck.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'adrs='+getHost( document.domain ),
        dataType:   'jsonp',
        jsonp:  false,
        jsonpCallback: 'methodCallback',
        success: function( data ) {
            if( data.message == "yes" ) { return yes;

            } else {


            return no;
            }
        }, 
        error: function( error ) {
            console.log( error ); 
        }
    });
```

by line `return the value **yes** or **no** to php function` I mean can I have php function which will call the above ajax script get its returned value ..

**EDIT**

After after some research I got to know that I can't return ajax value to php function.

Can I have the same functionality above ajax is doing in curl and how?

Comment: return to what PHP function? you need to make another AJAX call for that... or actually just use trck.php

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do or what you're really asking.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter no not another ajax call or not  trck.php.. see my updated question

Comment: you can not have jquery/javascript code inside a php function and return a value from it... PHP is in server side and Javascript/jquery is in client side!!!

Comment: @AyyappanSekar thanks..can i do the same jsonp functionlity with curl...? i think using curl instead of ajax jsonp  can return the value to php function ??right?

Comment: where do you want to access the yes/no response? i mean, in which page?

Comment: @AyyappanSekar lil bit confused what are u asking ?

Comment: if you need to use the yes/no response in some php page, you need to use another ajax call to the target page.

Comment: @AyyappanSekar ok..but that will not work ....can i have the function i need using curl ?

Comment: sorry am not aware of curl :(

Comment: What do you exactly wants to do?

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want to do?

**PHP** is *STATELESS*. That means you can NOT get any data back from the client to *continue* the script. If you call it back, the script will start again from the beginning like it has never been started.

Then **curl** can be used to connect to a *server*, you *client* is a **client**. That mean if he do not called you, the router/firewall will deny you the route.

**The possible solutions :**

- If you really want to 'push' data Then, you should use  [PHP SOCKETS](http://socketo.me/). I never tried, so I can't give you more informations.
- Send a unique token with you PHP answer and make a second AJAX call with this token. If the token is correct, then you can send a new data, you know in wich state is you client & wich client it is.
- Change your architecture or the way you think it. If the data is not correct, then, ask for the data again!